# Problems with requirements.txt when deploying to streamlit cloud

Tags: python, deployment, streamlit, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy an app on streamlit cloud. I am having trouble with the requirements. I am new to this and I am kind of lost, any help would be welcomed.

This are my requierements:

```
altair==4.2.0
atomicwrites==1.4.0
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
blinker==1.5
brotlipy==0.7.0
chart-studio==1.1.0
click-plugins==1.1.1
cligj==0.7.2
commonmark==0.9.1
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
gitdb==4.0.9
GitPython==3.1.29
jupyterlab==2.2.6
llvmlite==0.39.1
mistune==0.8.4
mkl-fft==1.3.1
mkl-random==1.2.2
mkl-service==2.4.0
munch==2.5.0
openpyxl==3.0.10
patsy==0.5.2
Pillow==9.0.1
plotly==4.14.1
protobuf==3.16.0
pyarrow==10.0.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.7
pydeck==0.8.0
Pympler==1.0.1
pyproj==3.3.1
pytest==2.0.0
pytz==2021.3
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
pywin32==302
PyYAML==6.0
rich==12.6.0
scikit-plot==0.3.7
semver==2.13.0
Shapely==1.8.2
sip==4.19.13
smmap==5.0.0
statsmodels==0.12.1
streamlit==1.14.0
toolz==0.12.0
tzdata==2022.6
tzlocal==4.2
Unidecode==1.1.1
validators==0.20.0
watchdog==2.1.9
webencodings==0.5.1
wincertstore==0.2
xgboost==1.7.1
setuptools==65.5.0


This is the error:
```

Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [32 lines of output]
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0.6.14.tar.gz
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/pip-install-5kqege4_/pytest_00f928899bf74cf6ba8e4e5d8f91fa52/distribute_setup.py", line 143, in use_setuptools
raise ImportError
ImportError

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "/tmp/pip-install-5kqege4_/pytest_00f928899bf74cf6ba8e4e5d8f91fa52/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
      use_setuptools()
    File "/tmp/pip-install-5kqege4_/pytest_00f928899bf74cf6ba8e4e5d8f91fa52/distribute_setup.py", line 145, in use_setuptools
      return _do_download(version, download_base, to_dir, download_delay)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-5kqege4_/pytest_00f928899bf74cf6ba8e4e5d8f91fa52/distribute_setup.py", line 123, in _do_download
      tarball = download_setuptools(version, download_base,
    File "/tmp/pip-install-5kqege4_/pytest_00f928899bf74cf6ba8e4e5d8f91fa52/distribute_setup.py", line 193, in download_setuptools
      src = urlopen(url)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
      return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 523, in open
      response = meth(req, response)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 632, in http_response
      response = self.parent.error(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 561, in error
      return self._call_chain(*args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
      result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
      raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
  urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: SSL is required
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.3; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/appuser/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Checking if Streamlit is installed

Comment: Can you share the actual app code?

Comment: i face the same issue too